# Polynomial rings with cardinal powers

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, commutative-algebra, set-theory

I was thinking about polynomial-like rings with a looser notion of powers. Probably, the notion I have in mind is the following:

Let $A$ be the commutative $k$-algebra generated by all symbols $x_i^\kappa$, for $1\leq i\leq n$ and $\kappa \leq \aleph_0$, subject to the relation $x_i^{\kappa} \; x_i^{\kappa'} = x_i^{\kappa + \kappa'}$. If well-defined, $A$ differs from the usual polynomial ring in $n$ indeterminates, because it also admits formal powers $x_i^{\aleph_0}$.

I guess that a category equivalent to that of $A$-modules should be the category of modules over the category (i.e., the category of functors to $k$) on $n$-fold product of the ordered set $\omega \cup \{\omega\}$.

Now, I am aware that what I wrote is likely ill-defined; I hope you nevertheless understand where I want to get with these things.

My question would be: is there a rigorous treatment of algebras built like that, at best with an analysis of their algebraic properties (e.g., which of all the nice statements about modules over polynomial rings fail for modules over this algebra/category)?